# Responsive Grid is not working - teaser component

Tags: aem

I am trying to use responsive behaviour of core components via proxy components. I am using OOTB teaser component.

- In editable template, I have added teaser component which have resourceSuperType core/wcm/components/teaser/v1/teaser
- I am in the layout mode and see the resposive layout.
- I tried to set the viewport of teaser component via dragging. It shrinks but when I release the key of mouse, it again take the default position. PFA

I am refering the wknd codebase.
AEM Env : 6.5.0

[image]

Comment: It appears to me that the grid styles might be missing. Behind the scenes the layout editor adds specific grid classes to components. If the grid CSS is missing, those added classes have no effect.

Comment: Out of the box, AEM provides a grid.less with the breakpoints, do you have a similar file for your project?